# In the collision of 2 divs, add a class in one of them using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two divs, one is static and the other has a continuous movement every 2 seconds.
What I want is that every time these divs collide, one of them (the static one) toggle a class.

I am using the `.getBoundingClientRect()`, but for some reason it is not working.

Can anyone see the problem in my code or tell me a better solution to do this without using libraries (pure Javascrit)?

Here is my code:

```js
var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
var object_1 = div1.getBoundingClientRect();
var object_2 = div2.getBoundingClientRect();

if (object_1.left < object_2.left + object_2.width  && object_1.left + object_1.width  > object_2.left && object_1.top < object_2.top + object_2.height && object_1.top + object_1.height > object_2.top){
        div1.classList.add("collide");
    }else{
        div1.classList.remove("collide");
    }
```

```css
#div1{
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: orange;
  animation: div1 2s infinite;
}

#div2{
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
  transform: translateY(40vh);
}

.collide{
  background: red !important;
}

@keyframes div1{
  to{
    transform: translateY(40vh);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Comment: Your script only runs once when it is first loaded and then not again. You'll need to watch for changes. Look at [Intersection_Observer_API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

Comment: @pilchard, that makes sense. I put all my script inside the `setInterval()` method with 1 second and now this is working :)